# ¿Cómo renderizar un componente de react (navBarWrapper) solapando otro componente?

Tags: reactjs, programación-móvil, menu

Tengo un componente Header, que renderiza un menú desplegable, que quiero que solape el componente que se muestra a continuación del header. ¿Un z-index para componentes de react existe??
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código de tus componentes para poder brindarte una ayuda más especifica?

Comment: No olvides mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].